# different sizes of postgres databases. move db from server1 to server2

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, psql

I'm trying to move a database from `server1` to `server2`. I read [docummentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/index.html) of postgres, and I think everything is right except that after I dumped db from server1 moved it and restored on server2 the sizes are different.

#### Server1

```
 SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('db_name'));                                                                                                   
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 118 MB
(1 row)
```

#### Server2

```
 select pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('db_name'));
 pg_size_pretty 
----------------
 81 MB
(1 row)
```

I've made the dump with `-a -Fc -Z9` flags and restore with `pg_restore -U user -c -d db_name dump_file.dump`

My questions are:

- Why the sizes are different?
- What is the correct approach to move a database like this if the application that access the db is a rails one? (I mean, I want a restore that doesn't affect future rails migrations)
- Do you have other ideas? Other docummentation that I can read?

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: You can read answers on this question [postgres backup / restore: restored database much smaller?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/37321), maybe it will help you find a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fine and normal.

Dump and reload produces a more compact database because there's no dead space in the tables and the b-tree indexes are newly reindexed so they're packed and well balanced. You'll find the size is the same or much closer if you:

```
VACUUM FULL;
REINDEX DATABASE mydb;
```

on the main DB.

On a side note, though, I *strongly* recommend restoring using the `-1` option to `pg_restore` unless you need parallel restore. That way you'll either get an empty DB or a complete restore. Of course, you should also always check the return codes from `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`.

No comment on the Rails part, I don't know what you're referring to. Please don't do multi-questions like this, they're hard to answer definitively and you get different "correct" answers in different parts. Post a new SO question for a new question.

Comment: Indeed everything was there. I counted entries in half of tables. Thank you for your tip using -1 for `pg_restore`. I'll use it when I have to update my db and prepare for the final migration :) Thanks a lot explaining me why the sizes are different. I know this is normal but I freaked out when I saw that ~1/3 difference.